# Warning! Token names and logos are not unique

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust

I mistakenly minted the same token on the mainnet twice, with the same name, symbol, and logo. A warning message appeared in response to this.
**Warning! Token names and logos are not unique. This token may have spoofed its name and logo to look like another token. Verify the token's mint address to ensure it is correct.**
To rectify the situation, I burned one of the tokens, reducing its supply to zero. Afterward, I updated the token's name, symbol, and picture. However, in my Phantom wallet, the name and symbol still appear as they did before, and a warning message continues to display on Solana Explorer. Are there any steps I can take to resolve this warning or any other actions I should consider to verify my token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a cache issue.
If you made modifications to your new token, you may have to wait a few days for everything to be updaed in cache.

Comment: Okay, that's great. 
By the way, how long does it take for the update to occur?

Comment: for my last experience, it took several days, but that was like a year ago, things may have changed in between